# How to add action when jQuery Mobile dialog closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I am using jquerymobile. I want to add an event when the dialog window is closed,just like the `$( ".selector" ).on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {} );`. Dose the dialog widget have the similar event.

Answer (score 0):

The [dialog](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/) widget is essentially just the page widget styled to look like a dialog so the normal page events will still fire. Based on your question it sounds like the [pagehide](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagehide/) should do what you want, here's a link to some of the other page [events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)

For example

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header"><h3>First Page</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#myDialog" data-rel="dialog" >Open Dialog</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"><h3>Footer</h3></div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="myDialog">
    <div data-role="header"><h3>A Dialog</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>A Dialog</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"><h3>Footer</h3></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#myDialog', function() {
   alert('Dialog hidden'); 
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAfUG/)